# Excluding specific cells from being copied when copy one Workbook to another Workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

The code I am using takes sheets as array and copies them as XlValues, but there are few cells containing formulas which I want to keep and paste as xlFormats. How can i achieve that?

```
Sub CopyPasteSave()
Dim NewName As String
Dim nm As Name
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Path As String, rcell As Range
Set rcell = Sheets("EPF Daily Report").Range("I5")
Path = "D:\"


If MsgBox("Copy specific sheets to a new workbook" & vbCr & _
"New sheets will be pasted as values, named ranges removed" _
, vbYesNo, "NewCopy") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False

' Copy specific sheets
' *SET THE SHEET NAMES TO COPY BELOW*
' Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
' Sheet names go inside quotes, seperated by commas
On Error GoTo ErrCatcher
Sheets(Array("InletManifold", "Separator", "Crude Strippers & Reboilers ", "Water Strippers  & Reboilers ", "Crude Storage&Export", "GSU,FLARE & GEN", "EPF Utility", "EPF Daily Report", "Choke Size")).Copy
On Error GoTo 0

' Paste sheets as values
' Remove External Links, Hperlinks and hard-code formulas
' Make sure A1 is selected on all sheets
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Cells.Copy
ws.[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Cells(1, 1).Select
ws.Activate
Next ws
Cells(1, 1).Select



' Remove named ranges
For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
nm.Delete
Next nm

' Input box to name new file
'NewName = InputBox("Please Specify the name of your new workbook", "New Copy")

' Save it with the NewName and in the same directory as original
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & " " & "EPF Daily Report" & " " & rcell.Value & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

.ScreenUpdating = False




End With
Exit Sub

ErrCatcher:
MsgBox "specified sheets do not exist within this work book"
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the cells you want to copy as formulas and formats at the same address in each sheet, for example D1 and H2 in each sheet? And do the formulas refer to any of the named ranges that you've deleted?

Comment: Dear,yes with the same address for each sheet like ("B11", "B12") cells which contains formulas i want to keep for example: sum(B5:B10) or for average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've done below, after the sheets are copied as values, is to copy cells that you specify from the original workbook, using `PasteSpecial` to keep their formulas intact. A couple of notes:

- Added an array, `CellsToCopy`, that contains the addresses, e.g., B11 and B12 that
  you want to copy with formulas. Mdoify this as needed.
- Added `wbSource` and `wbTarget` workbook variables, to refer to in the `PasteSpecial`
- Cleaned up your code, turning `DisplayAlerts` back on, and adding
  to the error handling
- Got rid of your `Select` statement and replaced with
  `Application.GoTo`

Also, note that you don't have to do anything special to keep the formats, as the copy as values will not have changed them.

```
Sub CopyPasteSave()
Dim wbSource As Excel.Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Excel.Workbook
Dim nm As Name
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CellsToCopy() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim Path As String
Dim rcell As Range

If MsgBox("Copy specific sheets to a new workbook" & vbCr & _
          "New sheets will be pasted as values, named ranges removed" _
 , vbYesNo, "NewCopy") = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
Set rcell = Sheets("EPF Daily Report").Range("I5")
Path = "D:\"
'Enter cells to copy with formulas
CellsToCopy = Split(("B11,B12"), ",")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Copy specific sheets
' *SET THE SHEET NAMES TO COPY BELOW*
' Sheet names go inside quotes, separated by commas
On Error GoTo ErrCatcher
wbSource.Sheets(Array("InletManifold", "Separator", "Crude Strippers & Reboilers ", "Water Strippers  & Reboilers ", "Crude Storage&Export", "GSU,FLARE & GEN", "EPF Utility", "EPF Daily Report", "Choke Size")).Copy
On Error GoTo 0
' Paste sheets as values
' Remove External Links, Hyperlinks and hard-code formulas
' Make sure A1 is selected on all sheets
Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws In wbTarget.Worksheets
    With ws
        .Cells.Copy
        .[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        For i = LBound(CellsToCopy) To UBound(CellsToCopy)
            wbSource.Worksheets(ws.Name).Range(CellsToCopy(i)).Copy
            ws.Range(CellsToCopy(i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        Next i
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.Goto .Range("A1")
    End With
Next ws
With wbTarget
   ' Remove named ranges
    For Each nm In .Names
        nm.Delete
    Next nm
    ' Input box to name new file
    'NewName = InputBox("Please Specify the name of your new workbook", "New Copy")
    ' Save it with the NewName and in the same directory as original
    .SaveAs Filename:=Path & " " & "EPF Daily Report" & " " & rcell.Value & ".xls"
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
End With

Exit_Point:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Exit Sub

ErrCatcher:
MsgBox "specified sheets do not exist within this work book"
Resume Exit_Point
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Doug you are genius,that "for" loop helped me a lot my issue is now solved,thanks a lot and thanks to Stackoverflow.com for providing such professionals who keep world of coding updated.

Comment: Dear Doug, what if the the excluded cells are different in each Worksheet,can you help me with that!?

Comment: I have two possible suggestions:  
1) Create a subroutine that you pass the worksheet name and ranges to exclude to. It would look like this sub, except you'd just pass one sheet name and an array of cell addresses. So you'd remove the sheet array and cell address array from inside the code.  
2) Replace the sheet and cell address arrays above with a two-dimensional array, with the first dimension holding sheet names and the second dimension holding comma-separated cell addresses, which you'd then split into `CellsToCopy`.